# Code Academy, Conditionals and Control Flow Grand Finale

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm using Code Academy and I began with Python. For the "Grand Finale" of Conditionals and Control Flow and this is the problem:

> "Write an if statement in the_flying_circus(). It must include:

```
if, elif, and else statements;
At least one of and, or, or not;
A comparator (==, !=, <, <=, >, or >=);
Finally, the_flying_circus() must return True when evaluated.
Don't forget to include a : after your if statements!"
```

and I know this is the format:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if condition:
        # Do Something!
    elif condition:
        # Do Something Else!
    else condition:
        # Do yet another thing!
```

Firstly, I don't know what exactly it means by conditions. I thought it meant condition using comparators in relation to the_flying_circus, but that showed an error message. Am I supposed to define the_flying_circus? If not is it already defined, and how would I know the definition? It says it's an invalid syntax error. Secondly, with the "#Do Something" I think I'm supposed to use strings, so a certain script shows up if the_flying_circus fulfills one of the 3 certain conditions, but since I can't figure out what to write for the conditions I don't know. Also, Code Academy did give an overview of if, elif and else statements, but I'm still shaky on the concept. An overview with a simplified example of what this would be used for in real life would be greatly appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0):

In all languages a condition is some expression that can evaluate to a boolean expression i.e 1<2 or anything else so lets take a look at the following code

```
def the_flying_circus():
    x = True
    if True and x:
        print "x is true"
    if 2 < 1:
        print "The universe is ending"
    elif 2>1:
        print "Ok sanity"
    else:
        print "the sky is falling"
    return True
```

So each conditional statement checks whether or not a condition is true, and evaluates the following statement at the end. Lastly return True so the method condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if 1>2 or 2==3:
        return False
    elif 4<3:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

You are defining the_flying_circus as a function. It uses > == and < as comparators.   It has if, elif, and else. It returns True.

The conditions are the things that could be true or false but have to be checked by the if/elif statement. "4<3" is a condition. It evaluates to false.

The "#Do something" comments could be anything. Print something, return something, call some other function, etcetera.

Maybe some kind of [beginner's tutorial](http://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/if-statements/) on if statements? Plenty through google.